# bower_components folder is ignored by brunch

Tags: node.js, build, bower, brunch

I'm Trying to set up my front-end build system with brunch but have an annoying issue that whatever I do brunch ignores *bower_components* folder and doesn't process anything in it.
this is my brunch-config.coffee file

```
module.exports = config:    
    files:
        javascripts:
            joinTo:             
                'js/app.js': /^app/
                'js/vendor.js': /^bower_components/
            order:
                before: [                    
                    'bower_components/angular/angular.js'
                ]
        stylesheets:
            joinTo:
                'css/app.css'
    paths:
        'public': 'build'       
    modules:
        definition: false
        wrapper: false
    plugins:
        assetsmanager:
            copyTo: '':['app/pages', 
                        'app/background.js', 
                        'app/manifest.json']
```

So js/app.js file always gets sucessfully compiled but vendor.js file is not there. Any Idea?

Comment: Do you have proper `bower.json` in place? Brunch only consumes packages specified in that file

Comment: Yes I do and angular is specified there

Comment: Please create an issue @ https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues with your OS, NPM, Node, Brunch versions; `config.coffee` & `bower.json`

Comment: @TaronMehrabyan Did you figure out why the `vendor.js`-file didn't compile?

Answer (score 0):

After I wrote my comment on the original question I figured it out and it was because I had my `bower.json`-file inside the `bower_components`-folder but it has to be in the same directory as the `brunch-config.js|coffee`-file is in.

So the directory-structure should look like this:

```
directory
- bower_components/
- app/
- bower.json
- brunch-config.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove your dependencies on the bower.json from top to bottom. When you catch this dependency try to use [read-components](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-components). That's worked for me.